# How to adapt CQRS to projects?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, cqrs

I came across a new term named [CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) which states that the conceptual model should be split into command model and query model as a typical CRUD model in which the command and query happens in the same model. The article has all theory information.

I don't understand how I should implement this in a project with ASP.net MVC3, EF 4.3 and jQuery.

Can anybody suggest me how to practically implement it in my project?

Comment: the most important thing is : do you need it? have a go on a green project, and try various real world scenarios. CQRS needs some extras that might turn a simple project into a complex one.

Comment: http://cqrs.nu/ (DDD + CQRS + event sourcing)

Comment: There's an article over on github about converting an existing project from a basic MVC over entity framework site to use aspects of CQRS - https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/wiki/Tutorial-0:-Quick-Northwind-sample. you might find that of use.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[CQRS Journey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx) is a good place to start. I also suggest you watch [A Journey into CQRS](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online-2012/A-Journey-into-CQRS) on Channel9.

Anyway, the best thing to learn CQRS is to try it by yourself. For me, I have to learn how to adapt it to my projects for around 6 months.

Comment: The _CQRS Journey_ is useless. The only thing you learn from it is what the pattern is about - an this is only one sentence - but there is not a single example how to implement it. Several pages about some stuff that doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 5):

This article has a detailed explanation.
[introduction to cqrs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS)

Comment: The CQRS implementation is completely wrong. It's build upon a repository that has the methods `Save` and `Get` which clearly violates the CQRS pattern. Why should I implement such an overengineered CQRS layer/abstraction on top of it? It's insane.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find sample code for asp.net mvc with cqrs. [CQRS with MVC](http://www.adamtibi.net/06-2013/implementing-a-cqrs-based-architecture-with-mvc-and-document-db).
Find more video here [CQRS with ASP.NET MVC - A Year On](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/CQRS-with-ASP-NET-MVC-A-Year-On)

Comment: thank you and i hope my another answer will help you on other topics.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out the classic example from Greg Young himself: [Simple CQRS example](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r)

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Its.CQRS: https://github.com/jonsequitur/Its.Cqrs which is being used in production at Microsoft.